# How to iterate the paragraph items in a Word document using office interop?

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop

How to iterate the paragraph items(like images, textboxes, etc., of a paragraph) in a Word document using office_interop?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can iterate though a document's paragraphs

```
foreach (Word.Paragraph paragraph in myDocument.Paragraphs)
{
   string pText = paragraph.Range.Text;
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pText);

   Word.InlineShapes shapes = paragraph.Range.InlineShapes;
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Shape Count: " + shapes.Count);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your suggestion. But my requirement is not to iterate through the paragraphs. I want to iterate a particular paragraph and access the members of that paragraph (like shapes, text boxes, etc.,)

Comment: Check my updated answer. Basically you can use `paragraph.Range.InlineShapes`.